# gitlab CI + Docker + .NET Core, I don't understand why only an older .net version is installed

Tags: docker, .net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab CI file that is building projects like this:

```
image: 'docker/compose:1.25.1-rc1'
services:
    - 'docker:dind'
variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

    stages:
        - build
        - deploy

    buildCode:
        stage: build
        except:
          - deploy
        script:
            - docker build -t dataserver -t ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest -f dockerfile .

    deployCode:
        stage: deploy
        only:
          - deploy
        script:
            - docker build -t dataserver -t ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest -f dockerfile .
            - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
            - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest        
            - docker network create network && echo 'creating network'
            - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml pull
            - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml rm -f -s
            - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

The idea is to use docker/compose:1.25.1-rc1 to bring a docker-compose environment and build the files.

The docker file itself is calling for this image to build

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as build

and then uses this image for runtime:

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 as final

so .net 3.1 should be installed.

however, when I run the app, I get this:

[image]

(I can't do a text capture, so this is a screenshot)

Which means that .net 3.1 is not installed and I can't figure out the problem.
If I compile the app for 3.0, with the same CI setup, it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try force a docker image pull of the images before build yours.

Seems your aspnet:3.1 
Just had the 3.1.0-preview version when you pulled It.

The 3.1 tag aims always the last 3.1.xxx version.

Before release was the preview.. now is 3.1.0... in Future Will be 3.1.x.

If you already has pulled the image with the tag 3.1 your build will used the met image. And that may not be the current 3.1 in remote repository. If you pull It the hash is verified and will update the image If needed

Comment: since we're running our own ci agents, would it make sense to simply wipe them, so there is no cache left, and restart them?

Comment: @Thomas do you are using what gitlab-runner executor? If you are using a shell runner, then the image is cached in the docker, wipe the runner and / or restart the gitlab runner will not clean the cached image.. you may add a job to update the netcore images or just add the pull command in the build job..

Comment: @Thomas, I see your deploy job still doing a build of a image, I would suggest to remove those build and let the build's job to create/build all your required images and deploy's job would just login / pull your built images / and up the services.

I am not sure why you have this docker build in deploy's job